# Can an HTML page be cached which has a link to dynamic JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http, caching

Can I make the browser cache myPage.html and myStaticJS.js, yet not cache myDynamicJS.php?  I've tested the following, and myDynamicJS.php is definitely not being cached on my FF browser (the time changes), but viewing my Apache access log shows that myPage.html and myStaticJS.js are also not being cached.

myPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>What time is it?</title>
        <script src="myDynamicJS.php"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>My static cached HTML</div>
        <div>The time is <span id="now"></span></div>
    </body>
    <script src="myStaticJS.js"></script>
</html>
```

myDynamicJS.php

```
<?php
    header( 'Content-type: text/javascript' );
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    echo('var now="'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'";');
?>
```

myStaticJS.js

```
document.getElementById("now").innerHTML=now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make it not cached. By cache control headers inside php:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Or by adding dynamically controlled parameter to url so scripts url is different (might not be best idea because browser cache will try to cache each version... but it can be useful when you cannot make it php or control headers):

```
<script src="myNotCachableJS.js?s=<?php echo rand(1000,100000); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: myDynamicJS.php is not being cached even without these headers.  My desire is for myPage.html to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

Php is never cached since it is run server-side. The best way to cache (or rather, tell the browser to cache) is via `.htaccess` (or `http.conf` if you have access to that):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType text/html               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript  "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

You can change that to "access plus 1 year" or any timeframe you like.

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks Tobi,  Let me play with http.conf.  I am, however, pretty sure the browser can cache PHP (or at least the resultant HTML/XML/whatever that is received by the browser).  Typically, ones problem is preventing it from doing so.

Comment: Exactly, the result that gets sent to the browser is what's cached. HTML, XML, JSON etc. BTW, to not cache set "access plus 0 seconds". I think the [html5boilerplate](http://h5bp.com) has a pretty good .htaccess example for caching, setting proper MIME types etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `FilesMatch` directive to only add cache headers to files that end in extensions which you choose:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|js)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

This should, in theory, exclude your dynamic JS since it will have a PHP extension, but include the two other files.